# Simple Insert, Update to SQL Server

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, database, drop-down-menu

I have simple code like this

```
 using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Configuration;

protected void Add_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                string strConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SqlServerCstr"].ConnectionString;

            SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(strConnectionString);

            string musteriadi = DropDownList1.SelectedIndex.ToString();
            string avukat = DropDownList2.SelectedIndex.ToString();
            string query = @"UPDATE AVUKAT SET MUSTERİ = @musteriadi, AVUKAT = avukat";

            SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand();
            myCommand.Connection = myConnection;

            myConnection.Open();
            GridView1.DataSource = myCommand.ExecuteReader();

            GridView1.DataBind();
            GridView1.Visible = true;

            myConnection.Close();
        }
```

Where is the error? Simply, i want to add two column in my AVUKAT table,

How can i solve it?

Comment: actually i don't know :(

Comment: You need to use Try,Catch to see what is error Soner.

Comment: if you really want to add two columns to the table then the syntax is ALTER TABLE, an UPDATE query updates an already existing record with new values in existing fields.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is that you dont read the documentation for SQL, beginners, pagfe 1 pretty much.

> Simply, i want to add two column in my
>   AVUKAT table,

this is not what you do.

> string query = @"UPDATE AVUKAT SET
>   MUSTERİ = @musteriadi, AVUKAT =
>   avukat";

This is not valid SQL. Point. UPDATE is not ther to insert, it is there to CHANGE VALUES IN EXISTING ROWS. On top of that, what you write is not even vlaid per SQL syntax for an UPDATE clause which has a different syntax.

If you read the error messae you can slowly start - with the help of google - to learn the syntax of SQL. Or you jsut get a book on SQL 101.

If you dont like readingthe error message, posting it here would make me more inclined to offer more detailed help.

Answer (score 1):

In the C# code, you need to create a SqlParameter if you want to use @musteriadi.  In addition you cannot refer to the avukat variable as you do.  Take a look at some examples of how to use the SQLCommand as well as the sql syntax.